# Does stack unwinding really require locks?

Tags: c++, gcc

I've been profiling my code with mutrace and have the following interesting/worrying results:

```
Mutex #1260690 (0x0x7f87bc8eea40) first referenced by:
    /usr/lib/mutrace/libmutrace.so(pthread_mutex_lock+0x49) [0x7f87be0b76b9]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1(_Unwind_Find_FDE+0x26) [0x7f87bc6eb0e6]

mutrace: Showing 10 most contended mutexes:

Mutex #   Locked  Changed    Cont. tot.Time[ms] avg.Time[ms] max.Time[ms]  Flags
1260690 19066789  1509831   109753     3600.883        0.000        0.226 M-.--.
```

The `_Unwind_Find_FDE` seems to have to deal with stack unwinding.

My application is highly multi-threaded with quite strict latency requirements and so I'd like to eliminate this as easily as possible. Are there any compiler or environment settings I can use to get rid of this function call, without rewriting my code? We do use exceptions for part of the flow control (probably unwisely) but it'd be a big refactoring job to fix that.

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
```

Comment: _" We do use exceptions for part of the flow control"_ then you have to pay that price (and you're lucky no one is throwing stones at your windows LOL)

Comment: Unfortunately I think you're going to have to fix your mistake and not use exceptions for flow control in the hot path. Anything else would be a hack.

Comment: Exceptions should *not* be part of normal program flow, they are supposed to be *exceptional*. And if you throw exceptions, your strict latency requirements can't really be that strict because stack unwinding is usually not very efficient.

Comment: The normal C++ contract is that object destructors are automatically called while unwinding the stack.  My crystal ball is saying that you are just seeing the plumbing that takes care of that.

Comment: @Hans Passant, yes obviously. I'm just surprised that unwinding a 'stack', a phrase which implies it belongs to only one thread, requires a lock. It seems bizarre. I'm going to see if clang behaves any differently.

Comment: @James: in the abstract, I agree.  But if your "single thread" in interacting with *other* threads locks a resource that is mutex controlled by a class, then I'd expect the class destructor to attempt to clean up the resource, and that's where you might encounter the mutex.

Comment: I have used exceptions in the past for flow control (albeit not using C++) and event handling. The subject was the controlling of a telephony card it's buffer underflow overflow and digit reception handling. So contrary to other comments I can say that for me has been a wise decision.

Comment: @IraBaxter: But wouldn't leaving the function on the sunny path require the destruction of the very same objects anyway?

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: There is nothing substantially wrong with using exceptions for flow control, in fact they _are_ a form of flow control. The important thing which most people using exceptions for that purpose are not getting is the _"exceptional_" bit. It is perfectly good to e.g. throw and have the stack unwinding take out the garbage for you if something didn't quite go the way you like (not even necessarily a fatal error) -- instead of writing much more complicated code. The point is, this happens mabye 1% of the time, and _doesn't_ in the other 99%, and usually in cold code.

Comment: Which backtraces are most frequent? Your profiler should show them, it not, try to gather them manually with gdb (just hit ctrl-c at random moments and print backtraces, look if tip portions of many of them look the same).

Answer (score -2):

Stop using exceptions if you need low latency.

Comment: Exceptions do not affect run-time if they are not thrown. Low latency can be achieved safely with exceptions.

Comment: Stop using "slow" exceptions if they exceed your latency requirements.  A good implementation need not have "slow" exceptions. If your implementation is not good, then, well, ...

Comment: @AlexShtof "We do use exceptions for part of the flow control". This answer is 100% correct. You cannot complain about the latency of exceptions when you use them for something they're specifically not designed to handle.